# Load website thumbnail image in swift?

Tags: swift

Hello people of the internet!

Quick question - anyone know how to load the thumbnail image (that appears when you copy and paste a link somewhere and you see the small image attached with it) from a site in swift?

I know the code for loading images is:

```
let url = NSURL(string: image.URL=)
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!) //only loads if the entire webpage is just an image
imageURL.image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

but that won't help with loading the thumbnail image. I believe websites use meta tags but I'm not 100% sure.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Several things here...

> appears when you copy and paste a link somewhere and you see the small image attached with it

With

> somewhere

I'm gonna assume you mean a service like Facebook or Twitter.

To answer your question, the URL of the image for a website is declared in the meta tags. Different services uses different tags.

Facebook uses

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/image.jpg" />
```

Twitter uses

```
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">
```

So those is where those URL's come from.

Now, what you call a 'thumbnail' is really created by whatever platform you are using, by sizing down the image loaded in the above URLs.

So to answer your question there is no magic formula to load a thumbnail image from a site. If you want to have a small thumbnail image from the content of a site, you will have to first 'crawl' the meta tags looking for one that gives you a full size image. Then you will have to load that and then you will have to resize it yourself.

As for code to resize, NSHipster has a full range of options for you http://nshipster.com/image-resizing/

For example:

```
let size = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(image.size, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5))
let hasAlpha = false
let scale: CGFloat = 0.0 // Automatically use scale factor of main screen

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, !hasAlpha, scale)
image.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size))

let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response juan! But any idea on how to pull the meta image itself? Or at least crawl the doc for the meta image?

Comment: You would have load the html content first. For that something like this will work:

```
var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com")
var htmlData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
var html: String = NSString(data:htmlData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

For parsing the tags, you can use something like this:

https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Swift-HTML-Parser